Multer req.file undefined
I used Multer to upload image into database and save it in folder name "uploads". But when i test it on Thunder Client, it showed the code "req..file" is undefined. Here the FoodRoutes code:
import express from "express"
import { addFood } from "../controller/foodController.js"
import multer from "multer"

const foodRouter = express.Router()

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()} + "-" + ${file.originalname}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage})

foodRouter.post("/add", upload.single("image"),addFood)



export default foodRouter;

And the Controller:
import foodModel from "../models/foodsModel.js";
import fs from 'fs'


// add food item

const addFood = async (req,res) => {
    let image_filename = `${req.file.filename}`
    const food = new foodModel({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        image: image_filename
    })
    try {
        await food.save();
        res.json({success:true, message: "Thêm món ăn thành công"})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({success:false, message: "Lỗi khi thêm món ăn", error})
    }  
}

export {addFood}

The error say :
file:///C:/Users/kienk/OneDrive/Desktop/Nh%C3%A1p/BanDoAn/server/controller/foodController.js:8
    let image_filename = `${req.file.filename}`
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
    at addFood (file:///C:/Users/kienk/OneDrive/Desktop/Nh%C3%A1p/BanDoAn/server/controller/foodController.js:8:38)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kienk\OneDrive\Desktop\Nháp\BanDoAn\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\kienk\OneDrive\Desktop\Nháp\BanDoAn\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at done (C:\Users\kienk\OneDrive\Desktop\Nháp\BanDoAn\server\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:45:7)
    at indicateDone (C:\Users\kienk\OneDrive\Desktop\Nháp\BanDoAn\server\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:49:68)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kienk\OneDrive\Desktop\Nháp\BanDoAn\server\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:166:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:147:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)

Node.js v20.17.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I asked AI to fix but it couldnt solve anything. What should I do =( ??

Are you sure that your client is uploading the file with the correct headers set? The Content-Type should be set to multipart/form-data

HI, Please include  the API call from the front end as well, especially with the code populating the field "image".

I've just tested the api. I've not finished the frontend for this api. Do you think that's the reason why my code isn't working ? Sorry for my bad grammar =((

Your backend code is well set.
Something has been missed in the test data.
That is the reason for the error you receive now.
I have tested your backend code as below. Here I use the same backend code to make a test post request. And it successfully uploads the test file into the server. The file will be uploaded into a folder named upload.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const foodRouter = require('./foodRouter.js');

app.use('/', foodRouter);

const body = new FormData();
body.set('image', new Blob(['some image'])); // some blob/file content
body.set('name', 'somename'); // some text input

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('L@3000');
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    body,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

foodRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const foodRouter = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()} + "-" + ${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const addFood = async (req, res) => {
  let image_filename = `${req.file.filename}`;
  res.send(`image uploaded successfully :  ${image_filename}`);

  // const food = new foodModel({
  //   name: req.body.name,
  //   description: req.body.description,
  //   price: req.body.price,
  //   category: req.body.category,
  //   image: image_filename,
  // });
  // try {
  //   await food.save();
  //   res.json({ success: true, message: 'Thêm món ăn thành công' });
  // } catch (error) {
  //   res
  //     .status(500)
  //     .json({ success: false, message: 'Lỗi khi thêm món ăn', error });
  // }
};

foodRouter.post('/add', upload.single('image'), addFood);

module.exports = foodRouter;

Test run results
Console logs generated as :
L@3000
image uploaded successfully :  1734017292412 + "-" + blob
Guidance for you
Please go through the sample code in server.js. Take note of the FormData object creation and populating fields in it. Please ensure that the image content is assigned to the field bearing name 'image', it is mandatory, otherwise the backend will fail since the same name has been hardcoded in the middleware.

I've checked ur code but it keep showing the error
"Error: Response status: 500 at file:///C:/Users/kienk/OneDrive/Desktop/Nh%C3%A1p/BanDoAn/server/server.js:37:15 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kienk\OneDrive\Desktop\Nháp\BanDoAn\server\uploads\1734078662546 + "-" + blob' (but i've not test yet) =((

It is a node server program. You can run it as node server.js , please ensure that the file server.js in the working directory itself.
